# Angular 9 dynamically setting FormControlName to typescript variable

Tags: angular9, form-control

I am trying to dynamically set FormControlNames for select lists in a Reactive form but instead of **formControlName**, I'm getting **ng-reflect-name**.

My html code is as follows and I set the formControlName and ID on my select lists to the same value just for confirmation:

```
<div *ngFor="let questionOption of questionOptions; let i = index">
    <select [id]="questionOption['control']" [formControlName]="questionOption['control']">
    <option *ngFor="let option of questionOption['options']"> {{ option }} </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And this image shows ng-reflect-name being output inplace of the expected formControlName:

[image]

What can I try to resolve this?

UPDATE:

I have also found that my select lists do not reflect my selected option.
All my options are visible when I click on my list, I select my desired option but the displayed option remains unchanged.
However, when the form is submitted my console output displays my selected option.
The following image shows 2 select lists on the right which I had selected different options and submitted the form.
The console output on the left show the selected and submitted values.

[image]